# CRM 2011 Update System User when New account created

Tags: attributes, entity, dynamics-crm-2011, updates

I am trying to populate a field in the system user entity whenever a user creates an account. I keep getting errors when trying to retrieve the system user entity so that I can populate its attributes. My code is as follows:

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ITracingService tracingservice = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
               context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Get entity that fired plugin
                    Entity entMain = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                    //Make a String for the last activity entity
                    String strLastEntity = "";

                    //Make the entity for the user entity
                    Entity entUser = (Entity)service.Retrieve("systemuser", context.InitiatingUserId, new ColumnSet(new String[] { "new_lastactivityentity" }));

                    //Get the entity type that fired the plugin and set it to the right field for the user entity
                    if (entMain.LogicalName.Equals("account"))
                    {
                        strLastEntity = entMain.LogicalName;
                        entUser["new_lastactivityentity"] = strLastEntity;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracingservice.Trace("FollowupPlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

The error is:
Could not load file or assembly 'PluginRegistration, Version=2.1.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can someone explain how to get the system user so I can update its attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have an assembly reference that isn't installed on the server, in particular that is `PluginRegistration`.

You could place that dll in the GAC on the server, however this won't work for CRM Online (or in a Sandbox registration I believe).

Is `PluginRegistration` a reference to the Microsoft assembly used in the plugin registration tool? Generally speaking you don't need a reference to that in your project, so you could try removing the reference.